# Issues with Git large files flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, github, clone

I'm currently working on a project, The app.debug and kernel.bin files got so large, that I had to use git lfs to push into the repository. Which worked

Then, when the other developer merged and pulled the project from his own branch into his local machine this was the error he got.
[image]

The parent directory 'C:... is the directory of my local machine, which is not supposed to show at his end.

Tried a couple of fixes ..like

*Running flutter clean..
*Telling the person to install git lfs and pull again..
*Downloading the particular large file and adding it to the other developer's local directory

But, non of the above approach worked worked.. Please, how do I resolve this?

Comment: `The app.debug ` are you tracking your build folder, if yes you're not supposed to as its generated 'stuff'

Comment: No, am not tracking the entire build folder.. only the .debug which is in the build folder and also the .bin files

Comment: you dont need to track this

Comment: ask your coworker to run flutter clean or delete build folder and run project

Comment: Deleting the build folder worked.. Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned I don't need to track the .debug or .bin files, does it mean I don't need to push the build folder to the Repo.. if yes? I do I go about it?

Comment: nope, you just need to track your lib,android,ios and any other folder you need, check this https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/private-files

Comment: oh wow! okayy, thank you very much for this!